# Calculating absolute test-retest reliability

Tags: r, repeated-measures, panel-data, descriptive-statistics, reliability

I have data collected from same participants on the same test at three time points.  I would like to calculate the *absolute* test-retest reliability of the measure (not just the *relative* test-retest reliability).  For instance, I am not just interested in the stability of the rank order of participants's scores across time.  I am interested in the stability of the absolute level of participants' scores.  Which statistical coefficient(s) would be most appropriate for assessing absolute test-retest reliability of these data, and how can I estimate these in R?  Preferably, the metric would be easily interpretable by other researchers (e.g., on a 0-1 scale).  I provide a data example below.

My understanding is that Pearson correlation is a measure of *relative* not *absolute* test-retest reliability.  I have seen others suggest [using the intraclass correlation (ICC) for absolute test-retest reliability](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15705040), whereas others have argued [the ICC is also a measure of relative reliability](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0073990), and to use other indices instead, such as the [Smallest Detectable Change](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16980142), the [Standard Error of Measurement](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031940605612114), the [Repeatability Coefficient](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0073990), [Smallest Real Difference](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0073990), or [Bland-Altman Limits of Agreement](http://hrcak.srce.hr/index.php?show=clanak&id_clanak_jezik=202829&lang=en) as measures of absolute test-retest reliability.

Example data:

```
time1 <- c(0:10)
time2 <- c(1:11)
time3 <- c(1.1, 1, 3.3, 3, 5.5, 5, 7.7, 7, 9.9, 8, 10)
```

In the above example, the relative test-retest reliability (based on Pearson correlation) between T1 and T2 is 1.0.  However, the absolute test-retest reliability should not be 1.  I would like to be able to calculate the absolute test-retest reliability even when there are missing data.

Sources:

Bruton, A., Conway, J. H., & Holgate, S. T. (2000). Reliability: What is it, and how is it measured? Physiotherapy, 86, 94-99. doi: 10.1016/S0031-9406(05)61211-4

de Vet, H. C. W., Terwee, C. B., Knol, D. L., & Bouter, L. M. (2006). When to use agreement versus reliability measures. Journal of Clinical Epidemiology, 59, 1033-1039. doi: 10.1016/j.jclinepi.2005.10.015

Šerbetar, I. (2015). Establishing some measures of absolute and relative reliability of a motor test. Hrvatski časopis za odgoj i obrazovanje, 17, 37-48.

Weir, J. P. (2005). Quantifying test-retest reliability using the intraclass correlation coefficient and the SEM. The Journal of Strength & Conditioning Research, 19, 231-240.

Vaz, S., Falkmer, T., Passmore, A. E., Parsons, R., & Andreou, P. (2013). The case for using the repeatability coefficient when calculating test–retest reliability. PLoS ONE, 8, e73990. doi: 10.1371/journal.pone.0073990

Answer (score 3):

There are intra-class correlation cofficient (ICC) versions for both absolute and relative (aka consistency) agreement.
For R check out Matthias Gamer's 'irr' package on [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/irr/irr.pdf).

```
library('irr')

time1 <- c(0:10)
time2 <- c(1:11)
times <- cbind(time1,time2)

icc(times,model = "twoway",
    type = "consistency",
    unit = "single",
    r0 = 0,
    conf.level = 0.95)

#>>ICC=1 for consistency

icc(times,model = "twoway",
    type = "agreement",
    unit = "single",
    r0 = 0,
    conf.level = 0.95)

#>>ICC=0.957 for agreement
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know which ICC version of "absolute agreement" is (ICC[1,1], ICC[2,1], ICC[2,k], etc.)? (see below): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation#Calculation_in_software_packages

Comment: As far as I can see from the cran documentary, the irr package only supports random models. So it's ICC(1,1) for options "single"+"oneway",  ICC(1,k) for "average"+"oneway", ICC(2,1) for "single"+"twoway",  ICC(2,k) for "average"+"twoway".

Comment: Please note that this package does not allow missing data.  If people know about similar packages that allow missing data, it would be greatly appreciated.